# how to select elements from one array to another with grep in perl?

Tags: arrays, perl, grep, text-processing

I would like to capture a difference between files in `CWD` and files in `@files`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use Cwd qw[getcwd abs_path];
opendir CWD, getcwd;
@files=grep{!/^\./}readdir CWD;

push @files, ("foo.txt", "bar.txt");

for my $i (@files){
    @difference=grep { !/^\./ and $i!=$_ } readdir CWD;
}
print "$_\n" for @differenc
```

Now the currect dir has this files:

```
$ls
a.txt  e.txt  getopt.html
```

With this expression `push @files, ("foo.txt", "bar.txt");`
the array has these elements: `("foo.txt", "bar.txt", "a.txt", "e.txt", "getopt.html")`, which is correct but now I would like to select only those files, which are *not* in CWD:
`@difference=grep { !/^\./ and $i!=$_ } readdir CWD;`, so I am expecting the array `@difference` to have again `("foo.txt", "bar.txt")` only (I now this has no sense, it's for an example). But the print does not output anything, what is wrong?

Comment: As you wrote yourself, your example doesn't make much sense, which makes me wonder whether this is not a [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Consider explaining what you are trying to achieve and we might be able to give better answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are quite a few issues with your code:

- Your second `readdir` (in the `for my $i (@files)` loop) doesn't read anything since the first one (`@files=grep{!/^\./}readdir CWD;`) already read the whole directory. You could use [`rewinddir`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/rewinddir.html) first, but simply using a copy of `@files` (before pushing `foo.txt` and `bar.txt`) would be simpler and more efficient.
- You are using `!=` instead of `ne` to compare strings.
- Every iteration of your loop erases the previous value of `@differences` since you assign it with `=`. Presumably `push` would make more sense.
- The logic inside your loop is a bit flawed. `grep` returns the elements that satisfy the condition, but you are more interested in whether any elements satisfies it.
- You should check if `opendir` succeeded (by adding a `or die ...` to the `opendir` line). Also, note that `open my $CWD, getcwd` is equivalent to the simpler `open my $CWD, "."`.

What you probably wanted to do is something like:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

opendir my $CWD, "." or die "Could not open '.': $!";

my @files = grep{!/^\./} readdir $CWD;
my @init_files = @files;

push @files, ("foo.txt", "bar.txt");

my @difference;
for my $i (@files){
    push @difference, (grep { !/^\./ and $i eq $_ } @init_files) ? () : $i;
}
print "$_\n" for @difference
```

That's far from efficient however, and more complicated that it needs to be. I suggest instead:

```
my %files = map { $_ => 1 } grep {!/^\./} readdir $CWD;

my @difference;
for ("foo.txt", "bar.txt") {
    push @difference, $_ if ! exists $files{$_};
}
print "$_\n" for @difference
```

Note that I've added `use strict; use warnings;` to the script. Always add them to your codes. While in that specific case, it would not have helped you find out what's wrong, it will save you countless hours in the future. Also, always use lexical file/directory handles (that is, do `opendir my $CWD, "dir"` rather than `open CWD, "dir"`).

Comment: I use `$` only for variables and UPPERCASE for handles. It makes my code cleaner, why to mix them up?

Comment: @milanHrabos It does not make you code cleaner. First, it costs you nothing to add a `$` in front. Second, if you make a spelling mistake (like `CDW` instead of `CWD`), with `strict` and a `$`, Perl will issue an error at compile time. Without the `$`, the line will eventually fail, maybe silently, and you'll have a hard time debugging it. Third, using `my $` means that your variable is lexically scoped, which means that you won't have any issues when calling functions for instance.

Comment: @milanHrabos For instance, consider `sub f { open FH, "<", "f.txt"; $l1 = <FH>; g(); @rest = <FH> }` and `sub g { open FH, "<", "g.txt"; print for <FH> }`. Well, `f` is not working as you'd expect, since `g` is opening a file using the same variable as `f`, thus closing the file opened by `f`. If you had used `my $FH` instead, this would not be an issue.

Comment: @milanHrabos The idea that the scope of variables should be limited (eg by avoiding global variables (`CWD`) in favour of properly scoped variables (`my $CWD`)) is a fundamental tenet of computer science

Answer (score 1):

You have two `readdir` operations on the same filehandle. Once the first reaches EOF, there is nothing more to be returned.

Add a `[rewinddir](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/rewinddir.html) operation before the second iteration.